# Jetpack Navigation Compose Animation incorrect pop animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I use the library from the Accompanist Jetpack Navigation Computer Animation, when I press the back button, the animation I prescribed is not performed, but some other strange one.
[Video with animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Go0g3LI992y3RvU-ogAawup3WoiehoL0/view?usp=sharing)

```
AnimatedNavHost(navController = navController,
        startDestination = categoryScreenRoute,
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        })
    {
        composable(route = categoryScreenRoute) {
            CategoryScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
        }
        composable(route = itemsScreenRoute) {
            ItemsScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
        }
    }
```

I tried to prescribe an animation for each composable function, completely removed the animation of the transition back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**define an extension method**：

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.setComposable(
    route: String,
    arguments: List<NamedNavArgument> = emptyList(),
    deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = emptyList(),
    content: @Composable AnimatedVisibilityScope.(NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit){
    return composable(
        route = route,
        arguments = arguments,
        deepLinks = deepLinks,
        enterTransition = {
           slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
           slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        popEnterTransition = {
           slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        popExitTransition = {
             slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right, animationSpec = tween(speedAnimation)
            )
        },
        content = content
    )
}
```

**The method of use is as follows**:

```
AnimatedNavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = categoryScreenRoute) {
        setComposable(route = categoryScreenRoute) {
            CategoryScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
        }
        setComposable(route = itemsScreenRoute) {
            ItemsScreen(navController = navController, viewModel = viewModel)
        }
    }
```

**Your CategoryScreen Example**:

```
@Composable
fun CategoryScreen(viewModel: CategoryViewModel = hiltViewModel(), navController: NavController) {
    val categoryState by remember { viewModel.getAllCategory() }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        when (categoryState) {
            is ApiResult.Error -> {
                Text(
                    text = (categoryState as ApiResult.Error<List<Category>>).message.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W600
                )
            }
            is ApiResult.Exception -> {
                Text(
                    text = (categoryState as ApiResult.Exception<List<Category>>).e,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                    fontSize = 24.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W600
                )
            }
            is ApiResult.Success -> {
                val list = (categoryState as ApiResult.Success).data

                LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(2), contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp)) {
                    items(list) { category ->
                        CategoryItem(category) {
                            viewModel.selectCategory(category)
                            navController.navigateToItemsScreen()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Please send your code to GitHub and I can help you change it

Comment: You can continue to use the setComposable method we provided above, just copy it directly.

At the same time, we have modified your @Composable CategoryScreen code and updated it, you can just copy it directly.

Comment: It has a conflict with NavigatonDrawer. If I use slideIntoContainer() my NavigationDrawer shows as opened when animation is running

Comment: you can ask a new question, then ait me @AndreyLarionov